# How to merge value of child records into strong params in controller create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 app I have a `client` which can have a bunch of nested `people`:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @client = Client.new
    @client.people.build
  end

  def create
    @client = current_account.clients.build(client_params.merge(:creator_id => current_user.id))
    if @client.save
      flash[:notice] = "Client created."
      redirect_to edit_client_url(@client)
    else
      @client.people.build unless @client.people.any?
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def client_params
    safe_attributes = [
      :name,
      :people_attributes => Person::ATTRIBUTES + [:id, :_destroy]
    ]
    params.require(:client).permit(*safe_attributes)
  end

end
```

It turns out that we have to store the `account_id` with each `person` as well (each `client` belongs to an account already).

To achieve this I would like to merge `current_account.id` into each newly created `person` (as it's already done with the `creator_id`).

How can this be done?

---

One way of doing it would be in the `Person` model like this:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :account

  after_save :save_account_id

private

  def save_account_id
    update_column(:account_id, client.account.id) # does not feel right to me
  end

end
```

But this doesn't feel right to me since a Rails model (in my opinion) should be kept *stupid* and not know about e.g. its parent records (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I would prefer to do it in the controller. But how can it be done?

Comment: When a person belongs_to a client and the client has only one account why do you then need to copy the client.account.id to the account_id in the first place?

Comment: @spickermann, because I quite often have to output all the account's people like `current_account.people`. And having a join table "clients" in between them will generate far too many SQL queries.

Comment: Did you consider defining `has_many :people, through: :client` in the `Account` model? I would expect Rails to handle `current_account.people` without N+1 queries in that case. And you avoid hard to debug database inconsistencies when both columns are not in sync.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add it into the merge you already have setup.
Assuming you have access to client.account_id which I believe you would because you setup the belongs_to.  If not you would have to do a DB query to get it but once you have it you could just add it into your existing merge.  I have had to merge multiple params in other apps.

```
@client = current_account.clients.build(client_params.merge(
:creator_id => current_user.id,
:account_id => person.account_id
))
```

Comment: Thanks but in my case the `account_id` is actually in the `Person` model, not in the `Client` model. I wonder what the syntax for that is...

Comment: Try person.account_id perhaps?  If there is a relationship you should be able to access it like that.